# How to simulate "align-items: baseline" in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, flexbox

Since there is no "align-items: baseline" in RN's implementation of Flexbox, how can I align the baselines of two text element horizontally?

[image]

The JSX:

```
<View style={styles.numberAndPercent}>
  <Text style={styles.number}>6.80</Text>
  <Text style={styles.percent}>%</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I cannot grasp what effect you're talking about. Can you elaborate on what specifically you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

React Native now supports `alignItems: 'baseline'`, so the following should work:

```
numberAndPercent: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'baseline',
}
```

Flexbox docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html); full list of supported values [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignitems).

Comment: Thanks for your notice! Haven't look at React Native for quite a time, only to find out that many hard problems have been solved (this and things like text ellipsis) !

Comment: I don't see any support for `baseline` in the link you've given. Did they remove the support?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- I just added a [new link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignitems) to the full list of supported options. They still do support `baseline`.

Comment: is there baseline-start? hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{
  numberAndPercent: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }
}
```

And additionally:

```
{
  number: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end'
  },

  percent: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently React Native supports every Flexbox property except *baseline*. To get around with this issue, you can set the height to be the same as the font size.

```
textBig: {
  fontSize: 40,
  height: 40,
}
textSmall: {
  fontSize: 18,
  height: 18,
}
```

It's not a perfect solution but it gets the job done, for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text style={styles.numberAndPercent}>
  <Text style={styles.number}>6.80</Text>
  <Text style={styles.percent}>%</Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
{
    fontSize: 40,
    lineHeight: 40 * 0.75,
    paddingTop: 40 - (35 * 0.75), // <-- Add this
}
```