# Japanese text not vertical center on IOS when using custom font

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm facing an issue of centering japanese text vertically on IOS. Whenever I add Japanese to `PREFERRED LANGUAGE ORDER` list at `Language and Region` setting on IOS,

[image]

Japanese text will be upper than center and only Japanese, not English text. Everything works perfect on Android. I'm using custom font for more specific. Any one has an idea of how to resolve this?

[image: Japanese text (IOS)] `Japanese text (IOS)`

[image: Englist text (IOS)] `English text (IOS)`

[image: Japanses text (Android)] `Japanese text (Android)`

**Edit:**

The code that I use to center text:

```
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
```

Comment: In your case, you need to style the button layout using iOS-specific stylesheet. Can you show the stylesheet you used? And try `vertical-align: baseline;`

Comment: @Raptor I have updated the stylesheet that I used. Is `vertical-align: baseline` in react native because I can't find any document related to this

Comment: See [this demo](https://snack.expo.io/@raptorkwok/japanese-button-alignment-demo). Basically React Native can use all the CSS available by changing it to camel-case. I'm not using any custom font, though.

Comment: @Raptor It's probably because of custom font. When I comment out fontFamily, it works fine. And also I'm getting `verticalAlign is not a valid style property`

Comment: Alright. Probably the `alignItems` property included `verticalAlign` function. See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192143/how-to-simulate-align-items-baseline-in-react-native)

Comment: @Raptor If I use `alignItems: "baseline"` my text cannot be centered vertically button any more?

Comment: Did you tried giving `padding: 0` ?

Comment: Without using custom font, alignItems: baseline works fine. Which font are you using?

Comment: @Raptor I'm using Phenomena font

Comment: @Firu I have already tried that, adding `padding: 0` make no difference

Comment: I tried the custom font in Expo App in iOS device, seems working correctly. Same [demo link](https://snack.expo.io/@raptorkwok/japanese-button-alignment-demo)

Comment: @Raptor Have you tried `add Japanese to PREFERRED LANGUAGE ORDER list at Language and Region setting on IOS` ?

Comment: I added Japanese as Preferred Language, but still keeping English (US) as display language. Here is the screenshot of the result (still working as expected): https://imgur.com/4OYsznX. Additional info: I'm using iPhone XR, iOS 12.1.4

Comment: @Raptor hmm, it's strange. Your text with Phenomena font looks quite different from mine. Are you sure apply the font successfully? https://imgur.com/A6OTF3v

Answer (score 0):

Android has prop `includeFontPadding` with default value = false so this issue not happening on Android.

Anw, to resolve this issue on iOS, you can using Font Tool for XCode to edit your font, please read this article for more detail:

https://medium.com/@martin_adamko/consistent-font-line-height-rendering-42068cc2957d

Comment: @MinhDuc I face the same issue with you and this is my solution, can you share me why it is not working?

Comment: I followed exactly as your article and also re-linked the font after editting but there was no different

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution:

Use `TextInput` instead of `Text` also add **props** `editable={false}`

Example:

```
<TextInput style={{styles.yourStyle}} editable={false}>
  Your Japanese or whatever text goes here...
</TextInput>
```